# Unexplainable Crash in CLI DLL when App shuts down

Tags: crash, singleton, c++-cli

I have a CLI DLL (mixed pure C++ and managed code, VS2005) that I load into a C# application. All works fine, but when the C# application is closed (clicking the small "X" button in the titlebar of the main form) the application crashes with a message that tells me that an "**unknown software exception" (0xC0020001)** happened at address 07C812AEB. The title of the message is ".NET BroadcastEventWindow.2.0....."

It is not possible to find the cause because the Visual Studio Debugger does not halt on the crash location.

When I load the application into OllyDebug it shows me that the crash probably occurres deep in mscorwks.dll.

I use pure C++ classes and mixed classes all separated by `#pragma managed` and `#pragma unmanaged`.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

OK. Finally I reduced the code in my DLL until I did not get any crash anymore. I ended up with several classes empty and I found the culprit.

What I found is so weird and bare of any logic that I have to post my result here.

In one of the pure C++ classes (that does not contain any managed code) I use a **singleton** in the header file:

```
inline static CMyClass& Instance()
{
    static CMyClass i_Inst;
    return i_Inst;
};
```

Anything goes wrong here when the application exits that results in the crash.

When I remove the singleton and instanciate the class as a **global variable** in the CPP file like:

```
CMyClass gi_Instance;
```

the crash is gone!

I cannot see what should be wrong with my Singleton. I suppose this is a Visual Studio bug.

**NOTE:** I also use the same class with the same Singleton in a pure C++ DLL and there is no problem. The problem occurres only when compiling it in a CLI project.

**NOTE 2:** When I put an `OutputDebugString(L"Destructor CMyClass");` in the destructor of CMyClass I never see that message in the Trace as long as I use the Singleton. With the global variable the destructor is called correctly.